# How to get all records from two tables where doesn't exists in third

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to find a way to display a list of users that have cancelled a booking today.

The way my system works when a user cancels a booking is by adding a record into a cancellations table and deleting the record from the bookings table.

Currently I have

```
select distinct 
members.firstname, members.lastname, cancelations.time, cancelations.groupnumber 
from 
members inner join cancelations on members.memberid = cancelations.memberid 
where 
cancelations.date = "CURRENT_DATE"
```

This works perfectly fine, except, this will also show if a user moves their appointment to a later/earlier time as the system will cancel then re-book.

So i believe what I would need is something like:

select distinct *column names* from *tables* where cancelations.date = "CURRENT_DATE" AND **where the user hasn't got any records in the bookings table today**

Tables in use (simplified)

Members - memberid, firstname, lastname
Cancelations - cancelationid, memberid, date, time, groupnumber
bookings - bookingid, memberid,date,time,groupnumber

Comment: What if the rebooked appointment is for tomorrow?

Comment: The client would class this as a cancellation, good point though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use `NOT EXISTS()` which is exactly what you are asking for :

```
select distinct members.firstname, members.lastname, cancelations.time, cancelations.groupnumber 
from members 
inner join cancelations
  on members.memberid = cancelations.memberid 
where cancelations.date = "CURRENT_DATE"
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM bookings b
                 WHERE DATE(b.dateField) = DATE(cancelations.date)
                   AND b.memberid = member.memberid)
```

This checks that a record in the same day for the same member doesn't exists in `booking` table

Comment: Hi Sagi, i have substituted the correct columns in b.datefield and member[s].memberid however this isn't working, it's just resulting in no results when the condition is true and false

Comment: fixed with select distinct members.firstname, members.lastname, cancelations.time, cancelations.groupnumber 
from members 
inner join cancelations
  on members.memberid = cancelations.memberid 
where cancelations.date = CURRENT_DATE
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM bookings b
                 WHERE b.date = current_date
                   AND b.memberid = members.memberid)

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by changing your table structure for the `bookings` table.  Instead of storing the state of a cancellation across multiple tables, I would just add a new column to `bookings` called `isActive`.  This column will be set to `1` when a booking is created and will be set to `0` when one is deleted.  Also when a booking is restored, it will be set to `1`.  This is a common technique known as "soft" deletion.  It allows you to logically delete a record without actually removing it or moving it to another table.  At some later point, you can archive stale deleted bookings to another table.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings (`id` int PRIMARY KEY,
                       `memberid` int,
                       `isActive` tinyint
                       `date` datetime);
```

Now the query to find out if the user does not have any bookings from today is sane and straightforward:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM bookings
WHERE memberid = 1 AND
      date = CURDATE() AND
      isActive = 1
```

The query given by @sagi looks promising, but when you find yourself writing complex queries to answer simple business questions it might pay to think about the architecture.